# Mysql Driver not loaded Driver not loaded

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt4, pyside

MySQL works well before ,but when I use PyQt4 to connect it ,it prompts 
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: What OS, which version of Qt & PyQt, and how installed?

Comment: WinXP ，installed with the installer

Comment: try to see if your version of PyQt has MySQL driver. use `QtSql.QSqlDatabase.drivers()` to list all the SQL drivers that your PyQt has.

Comment: I solved it myself ，it is just code issue ,thanks